# java 8 stream groupingBy sum of composite variable

Tags: java, sorting, java-8, grouping, java-stream

I have a class `Something` which contains an instance variable `Anything`.

```
class Anything {
    private final int id;
    private final int noThings;

    public Anything(int id, int noThings) {
        this.id = id;
        this.noThings = noThings;
    }
}

class Something {
    private final int parentId;
    private final List<Anything> anythings;

    private int getParentId() {
        return parentId;
    }

    private List<Anything> getAnythings() {
        return anythings;
    }

    public Something(int parentId, List<Anything> anythings) {
        this.parentId = parentId;
        this.anythings = anythings;
    }
}
```

Given a list of `Something`s

```
List<Something> mySomethings = Arrays.asList(
    new Something(123, Arrays.asList(new Anything(45, 65),
                                     new Anything(568, 15), 
                                     new Anything(145, 27))),
    new Something(547, Arrays.asList(new Anything(12, 123),
                                     new Anything(678, 76), 
                                     new Anything(98, 81))),
    new Something(685, Arrays.asList(new Anything(23, 57),
                                     new Anything(324, 67), 
                                     new Anything(457, 87))));
```

I want to sort them such that the `Something` objects are sorted depending on the total descending sum of the (`Anything` object) `noThings`, and then by the descending value of the (`Anything` object) `noThings`

```
123 = 65+15+27 = 107(3rd)
547 = 123+76+81 = 280 (1st)
685 = 57+67+87 = 211 (2nd)
```

So that I end up with

```
List<Something> orderedSomethings = Arrays.asList(
    new Something(547, Arrays.asList(new Anything(12, 123),
                                     new Anything(98, 81), 
                                     new Anything(678, 76))),
    new Something(685, Arrays.asList(new Anything(457, 87),
                                     new Anything(324, 67), 
                                     new Anything(23, 57))),
    new Something(123, Arrays.asList(new Anything(45, 65),
                                     new Anything(145, 27), 
                                     new Anything(568, 15))));
```

I know that I can get the list of `Anything`s per parent `Id`

```
Map<Integer, List<Anythings>> anythings
            = mySomethings.stream()
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(p->p.getParentId(),
                    p->p.getAnythings()))
            ;
```

But after that I'm a bit stuck.

Comment: Yes, as I'm now looking at summing a variable on an inner object.  I've spent 2 days trying to figure this out.  It's not due to laziness that I'm here.

Comment: Would you like to sort your data in-place or would you like to generate sorted data structure from the existing one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless I'm mistaken, you can not do both sorts in one go. But since they are independent of each other (the sum of the `nothings` in the `Anythings` in a `Something` is independent of their order), this does not matter much. Just sort one after the other.

To sort the `Anytings` inside the `Somethings` by their `noThings`:

```
mySomethings.stream().map(Something::getAnythings)
            .forEach(as -> as.sort(Comparator.comparing(Anything::getNoThings)
                                             .reversed()));
```

To sort the `Somethings` by the sum of the `noThings` of their `Anythings`:

```
mySomethings.sort(Comparator.comparing((Something s) -> s.getAnythings().stream()
                                                         .mapToInt(Anything::getNoThings).sum())
                            .reversed());
```

Note that both those sorts will modify the respective lists in-place.

---

As pointed out by @Tagir, the second sort will calculate the sum of the Anythings again for each pair of Somethings that are compared in the sort. If the lists are long, this can be very wasteful. Instead, you could first calculate the sums in a map and then just look up the value.

```
Map<Something, Integer> sumsOfThings = mySomethings.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(s -> s, s -> s.getAnythings().stream()
                                                .mapToInt(Anything::getNoThings).sum()));

mySomethings.sort(Comparator.comparing(sumsOfThings::get).reversed());
```

Comment: I was going to post the same Solution. But I'd suggest to use `Comparator.comparing(Anything::getNoThings).reversed()` instead of the minus.

Comment: @Flown You are right, but for some reason the same does not work for the second comparator, and I guess I just wanted to keep it consistent.

Comment: Note that in the latter case you will sum noThings several times during the sorting as every comparator invocation will sum again for both compared Somethings.

Comment: @TagirValeev You are right, thanks for pointing this out! Edited.

Answer (score 0):

In the end I added an extra method to the `Something` class.

```
public int getTotalNoThings() {
  return anythings.stream().collect(Collectors.summingInt(Anything::getNoThings));
}
```

then I used this method to sort by total `noThings` (desc)

```
somethings = somethings.stream()
            .sorted(Comparator.comparing(Something::getTotalNoThings).reversed())
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

and then I used the code suggested above (thanks!) to sort by the `Anything` instance `noThings`

```
    somethings .stream().map(Something::getAnythings)
            .forEach(as -> as.sort(Comparator.comparing(Anything::getNoThings).reversed()));
```

Thanks again for help.

Comment: I have added inline code formatting to the class/variable names in your text. You may want to check whether I didn't accidentally change the meaning of anything -- hopefully not!

Answer (score 0):

The problem of other solutions is that sums are not stored anywhere during sorting, thus when sorting large input, sums will be calculated for every row several times reducing the performance. An alternative solution is to create intermediate pairs of (something, sum), sort by sum, then extract something and forget about sum. Here's how it can be done with Stream API and `SimpleImmutableEntry` as pair class:

```
List<Something> orderedSomethings = mySomethings.stream()
        .map(smth -> new AbstractMap.SimpleImmutableEntry<>(smth, smth
                .getAnythings().stream()
                .mapToInt(Anything::getNoThings).sum()))
        .sorted(Entry.<Something, Integer>comparingByValue().reversed())
        .map(Entry::getKey)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

There's some syntactic sugar available in my free [StreamEx](https://github.com/amaembo/streamex) library which makes the code a little bit cleaner:

```
List<Something> orderedSomethings = StreamEx.of(mySomethings)
        .mapToEntry(smth -> smth
                .getAnythings().stream()
                .mapToInt(Anything::getNoThings).sum())
        .reverseSorted(Entry.comparingByValue())
        .keys().toList();
```

As for sorting the `Anything` inside something: other solutions are ok.